# Mutating data in computed property also changed data in vuex store: why? Any help is appreciated

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

For my current project, I am working on a shop page. I am sending the data of each order made to my Laravel backend in order for it to be processed. Part of this data is an array with all the ordered products in it. I use `JSON.stringify()` on this array to avoid errors in the Laravel backend.

My issue is that when I stringify the array in a computed property, this also changed the data in my Vuex store for some reason. This in turn obviously causes quite a bit of error. Is this normal behavior, or am I doing something wrong? How can I avoid this from happening? Thanks in advance!

You can see my component's code in the snippet below.

```
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      order: "getOrder",
      countries: "getCountries"
    }),
    orderData() {
      let myOrder = this.order;
      if (myOrder.products) {
        myOrder.products = JSON.stringify(myOrder.products);
      }
      return myOrder;
    },
    country() {
      return this.countries.find(
        country => country.iso_3166_2 === this.order.country
      ).name;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    placeOrder() {
      console.log(this.orderData);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning to `myOrder` the reference of `this.order`, subsequently all your modifications inside it will affect `this.order` (so you are mutating).

In this case, since you just want to modify `products`, you can shallow copy `this.order` just like this:

```
let myOrder = { ...this.order };
```

Then, all the properties at the first level will have different pointers, so you can change them without fear of mutations.